# Render Razor variable inside AngularJS Html

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Html variable embedded within some Html that I retrieve from the database into an AngularJS $scope object. I then render this in a MVC/razor view using the ng-bind-html directive. A simple example follows:

**myView.cshtml**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <p ng-bind-html="pageSizeHtml"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**myCtrl.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageSizeHtml = '<div>Your page size is: @OurSystem.Configuration.PageSize</div>'
});
```

When I run this the rendered page looks like this:

```
    Your page size is: @OurSystem.Configuration.PageSize
```

But I want it to interpret the value of the Razor variable and look like this:

```
    Your default page size is: A4
```

Really stuck on this so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show a short, but complete page that demonstrates the issue? This should be fine if the angular app is contaied within a razor view, but not if it's a template or some other external source.

Comment: @BrendanGreen I added more explicit code example. Hopefully that will make things clearer. If not just ask.

Comment: That won't work.  The JS file won't run through the "razor engine" so it's treated as a string literal.  Best to use `ng-init` and pass it in from the view instead.  I have a working example I'll stick into an answer.

Comment: @BrendanGreen : Ah. That would make sense. The razor variable is interpreted on the server and the angularJS is interpreted afterwards on the client. I was hoping to use the Web API to return this data but I shall await your answer. Thanks for the prompt response. These things can take hours and hours!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current code won't work, because you are trying to use the razor syntax in a .js file, which won't be transformed by the razor engine.  Thus, you get the literal string instead.

An option is to use `ng-init` in the actual razor view to pass the value into the angular controller.

In your view:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="myInit(@OurSystem.Configuration.PageSize)">
      <p ng-bind-html="pageSizeHtml"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in the JS controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myInit = function(val) {
        $scope.pageSizeHtml = '<div>Your page size is: ' + val + '</div>';
    }
});
```

Note: having local issues testing the above code, but it should be pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

For using Razor in Javascript I have Html.Json extension:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{

  public static IHtmlString Json(this HtmlHelper html, object serializableValue)
  {
      return MvcHtmlString.Create(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serializableValue));
  }
}
```

If javascript has quoting issues with Razor, then you can just use it like that:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.pageSizeHtml = '<div>Your page size is: '+@Html.Json(OurSystem.Configuration.PageSize)+'</div>';
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Just read your code example more carefully, and I agree with Mr. Green, it won't work Out-of-box because Razor designed to transform just you cshtml views, not Javascript/CSS files. 
So you should move your js code as inline js of your cshtml, or use the magic trick described in the article below that allow you to do dynamic, razor-generated javascript/css files

http://blog.pmunin.com/2013/04/dynamic-javascript-css-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks @Phillipp Munin. I looked at your link and to be honest there's a lot of code there and I didn't really understand it. I now can see how Razor won't work in the way I'd like. However, I do need it to be dynamic though, so the returned HTML can have ANY razor configuration variable embedded within it not just the simple example I gave to illustrate. Food for thought. Thanks for your time.

Comment: THe @ symbol is causing errors for me.  Did you have to do anything additional?

Answer (score 1):

Razor is not executing it's own magic in *.js files.

Couple things you can do. Make a 'sharable servise' that razor will generate. Then reference it from you angular controller. Basically put your angular service in  cshtml file.

Or use init function to pass variable to your controller.
In your cshtml

```
<div data-ng-init="init({pageSize: @OurSystem.Configuration.PageSize})>
</div>
```

In your controlle add function:

```
init(parameters){
// parameters will be json object with pageSize property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Html.Raw`

```
@Html.Raw(OurSystem.Configuration.PageSize)
```

Comment: You can't use Razor syntax in a .js file.